# Batch script : Parse file and get particular line number substring

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I have a requirement for processing some files and renaming it. I am planning to use a batch process to execute it. 
The requirement is as follows

- Read the files in a particular directory
- Open all the TXT files in it.
- Navigate to a particular line in that    file.
- Parse that line to get a particular string.
- Use that particular string to rename the filename (or maybe copy to
  another    folder )

The line number that I need to extract is `12` and
the line has the following string `Product Number # 773339`.
What I want to extract from that line is `773339` and rename or create a new file as 773339.TXT with the same contents as original.

Below is the steps that I got so far, but not able to extract the substring yet

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (C:\Users\test\Desktop\AR\*.txt) DO (
    For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=:" %%a IN ('FindStr/N "^" "%%f" 2^>Nul') DO (
        If %%a Equ 12 (
            REM Get the line number here
            Echo %%a
            REM Get the string from that line number            
            ECHO %%b
        )
    )
    PAUSE
)
```

Comment: Looks like you are super close.  Now all you have to do is extract the number from `%%b`.  So just put that into another `FOR /F` command and use the `#` symbol as the delimiter. Or use the space as the delimiter and the number will be the 4th token.

Comment: BTW, before you go too far with this, I'd suggest you take a look at the output from `FindStr/N "^" "C:\Users\test\Desktop\AR\*.txt" 2^>Nul`, because altering your tokens and Delims just a little, could save you an entire `For` loop!

Comment: @Compo, yes.  Your are right. No need for a third nested `FOR` command.

Comment: You could also remove the `If` piping the numbered liines directly to `^|findstr "^12:"`

Comment: Try to put the lines `For /F "skip=11 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%%~f"') do set "LINE12=%%L" & goto :NEXT` and `echo(!LINE12:*:=!` into a sub-routine and call this in the body of your `for %%f` loop...